# Terraform kubectl_manifest error: metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, manifest, kubectl, kubernetes-custom-resources

I'm trying update an existing `kubectl_manifest` resource in my Terraform code but when I apply the changes, I get the following error:

```bash
Resource: "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1, Resource=customresourcedefinitions", 
GroupVersionKind: "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1, 
Kind=CustomResourceDefinition" 
Name: "prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com", 
Namespace: "" for: "/var/folders/7y/_yfb9pcn01s56rx2tpwfnwk80000gp/T/598050506kubectl_manifest.yaml": 
CustomResourceDefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io 
"prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com" is invalid: 
metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes

  on main.tf line 19, in resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd":
  19: resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd" {
```

Here is my Terraform code snippet:

```
data "http" "yaml_file" {
  url = var.crd_url
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd" {
  yaml_body         = data.http.yaml_file.response_body
  wait              = true
  wait_for_rollout  = true
}
```

**How to fix this?**

Terraform Version: `0.14.2`

AWS EKS Cluster Version: `v1.23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `server_side_apply` with `true` as its value in the `kubectl_manifest` resource and it fixed the error.

Changed code is as follows:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd" {
  yaml_body         = data.http.yaml_file.response_body
  server_side_apply = true
  wait              = true
  wait_for_rollout  = true
}
```

References:

- [Terraform / kubectl_manifest / server_side_apply](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/alon-dotan-starkware/kubectl/latest/docs/resources/kubectl_manifest#server_side_apply)
- [Kubernetes Documentation / Reference / API Overview / Server-Side Apply](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/)